# How to get latitude longitude upto 15 numbers ahead of decimal point

Tags: android, gps, android-gps

I am writing a code which gives me latitude , longitude and adress. But latitude and longitude are showing upto only 7 places after decimal point and i want it to be more accurate ie. upto 15 numbers after decimal points please help and thank you
following is my code where i am taking value by getLatitude & getLongitude

```
final String location = locationText.getText().toString();

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "dfdsfsd"+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("My success",""+response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "my error :"+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("My error",""+error);
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("locationText",location );



                    return map;
                }
            };
            queue.add(request);

        }
    });


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);

    }


    getLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getLocation();
        }
    });
}
private void launchCall() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(package_name, class_name));
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, this);
    }
    catch(SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationText.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + "\n Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        locationText.setText(locationText.getText() + "\n"+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)+", "+
                addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1)+", "+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2));
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 5):

> But latitude and longitude are showing upto only 7 places after decimal point

At the equator, a degree of latitude and a degree of longitude are each ~111 kilometers. Degrees of latitude are smaller closer to the poles.

7 decimal places is ~111/10000000 kilometers = ~0.0000111 kilometers = ~0.0111 meters = ~1.11 centimeters.

GPS is not accurate to even that level, let alone 15 places.

Comment: To tag onto this-  you need to learn the difference between precision and accuracy.  More digits is higher precision.  It is not higher accuracy.  0.2 can be higher accuracy than 0.1825733920.  The actual accuracy of the GPS  reading is returned as part of the callback.  It will give an accuracy in meters, and there's a 67% chance you're within that many meters of the location it returns.  Typical accuracies for GPS are 10-20m.  Typical accuracies for network location is 100-1000m.

Comment: thank you ... can you tell me if i move suppose 1 meter from my current position, by how much the latitude and longitude will change?

Comment: @YaseefSheikh: Your GPS position is unlikely to be affected by such a small movement. As [Gabe Sechan pointed out in the preceding comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544354/how-to-get-latitude-longitude-upto-15-numbers-ahead-of-decimal-point/48544450?noredirect=1#comment84084191_48544450), a GPS fix is likely to only be accurate within 10-20m.